# jQuery , angular 2 Material Select multiple dropdown initialize and re-initialize Issue (Getting different values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, material-design

jQuery Material Select multiple dropdown initialize and re-initialize Issue (Getting different values) angular 2

I am getting different values on initialize time.

> here I am getting value like "1: 1" , "2: 2"....

```
$('select').material_select();

<select id='country' multiple>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Country</option>
 <option [value]="option.Id" *ngFor="let  option of CountryList">{{option.CountryName}}</option> // here I am getting value like "1: 1" , "2: 2"....
</select>
```

but when I reinitialize again, I am getting value which starts from

> here I am getting value like "48: 1" , "49: 2"....

```
<select id='country' multiple>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Country</option>
 <option [value]="option.Id" *ngFor="let  option of CountryList">{{option.CountryName}}</option> // here I am getting value like "48: 1" , "49: 2"....  
</select>
```

I have destroyed multiple dropdowns

```
$('select').material_select('destroy');
```

then initialize again by using this code

```
$('select').material_select();
```

I am not able to get why this issue happens, I have checked by using another browsers but getting the same issue.